# Remove the beginning of a controller's name from the route

Tags: asp.net-core

I'm programming a booking engine. To keep an overview of the sequence of the various steps, the controllers are named like this:

- Step1_PersonalDataController
- Step2_OptionsController
- Step3_PaymentController
- Step4_ConfirmationController
- etc.

For the routing I'd like to remove **"Step"** so that the URLs become like **1_PersonalData** instead of **Step1_PersonalData**.

Is it somehow possible to define a routing rule in the Startup.cs to reach this goal? Of course it would also be possible to specify the [Route] attribute on each controller, but I want to avoid this solution and have a rule that is specified centrally in the Startup.cs

Comment: I would not recommend to use names like that as it breaks all conventions. Instead use the documentation option (/// <summary>) to add this kind of information.

Answer (score 0):

Please add the **Route** attribute on top of the controller Step1_PersonalData. eg:

```
[Route("1_PersonalData")]
```

Comment: Yes this would be an option, but I'd like to set a common rule in the Startup.cs so that it will apply for all Controllers and I won't have to specify it manually for each controller. I'm going to edit my question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Controller names don't have to be attached to route paths. For instance you can use the Route() attribute to define the route for the controller and you can use HttpGet("path") or HttpPost("path") to add to the route path for the method. Perhaps the routes could be /step/1 and /step/2 ?